# Do I need to Close a fsockopen Connection?

Tags: php

I just had a look on the PHP fsockopen Function and wondered if I have to Close the Connection after using it.

In the php.net manuel it said that it opens a connectionless Connection (?!?!), 
Background is just an easy external Linkchecker.

Do I need to close it? If yes how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to close it. You close it with `fclose()`.

If you don't close it in your code, it will be closed automatically when the script exits.

Whether the socket has a connection or is connectionless depends on the type of socket. If it's a TCP socket there's a connection, if it's a UDP socket there's no connection, because UDP doesn't have connections. But this is irrelevant to whether you need to close it; even with a connectionless protocol, the emulates a connection by binding to a particular port number and receiving the data on that port.

Comment: OK Thanks for your answer! Im probalbly going to open a few as the Link checker should check our hole site. So should I Close it right away or leave it until the script Ends?

Comment: You can reuse the same socket to get multiple URLs from the same server. See the HTTP protocol specification of persistent connections.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php

in every example it shows "fclose($fp);"

is that what you're asking?